# Pyfpdf Turkish Character in Python

Tags: python, pyfpdf

I want to create a pdf in my Python application using a text that contains Turkish characters, but I get an error. My codes are below. How can I fix this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from fpdf import FPDF
import os

def add_image(image_path):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()

    epw = pdf.w - 2 * pdf.l_margin
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14.0)
    txt = u'ATATÜRK LİSESİ 2019 2020 EĞİTİM ÖĞRETİM YILI 11C SINIFI'
    stxt = txt.encode('iso-8859-9')
    pdf.cell(epw, 0.0, stxt, align='C')
```

I get an 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0130' in position 60: ordinal not in range(256)' error if I use the codes below

```
epw = pdf.w - 2 * pdf.l_margin
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14.0)
txt = 'ATATÜRK LİSESİ 2019 2020 EĞİTİM ÖĞRETİM YILI 11C SINIFI'
#stxt = txt.encode('iso-8859-9')
pdf.cell(epw, 0.0, txt, align='C')
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: FYI only: that error message is correct. The Latin-1 encoding does not contain the capital latin letter i with dot above. Maybe try another encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded 'tr-arial.ttf' font to the application folder and i found this solution:

```
epw = pdf.w - 2 * pdf.l_margin
txt = u'ATATÜRK LİSESİ 2019 2020 EĞİTİM ÖĞRETİM YILI 11C SINIFI'
pdf.add_font('tr-arial', '', 'tr-arial.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('tr-arial', '', 11)
pdf.cell(epw, 0.0, txt, align='C')
```